# How to play old Minecraft PE maps with a newer version?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was making a MCPE map to upload on the Internet but when i upgraded my MCPE to 0.14.0, i could not open my old map. It is telling me,"A newer version of the game has saved this level. It cannot be loaded."
Please help me!!

Comment: When I upgraded to 0.9 the h*ll came. I lost ~18 months worth of roller costers

Comment: Can't somebody answer this?

Comment: Shouldn't this just result in chunk errors, or is that only in Java edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I founded out the answer. The map was made in Minecraft build 1 but i changed my version to build 4 after that. Thats why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Same to me. But try to change the mode. If you in survival mode, then you can change to creative mode. Hope it will work.